# Show mysql data where username is the same

Tags: php, mysql, database, match

I have a mysql table which has data from all flight bookings on my booking system. When a user books a flight, the details of that booking are stored in that table along with their username.

Now, I'm making a page where all of the user's previous flights are shown in a HTML table, and everything works except the code which filters results to those only from that user.

This is the (part of) code I'm using;

`$query_string = "SELECT name, seats, departure, destination, class, username, miles, timestamp FROM $tablename WHERE username IN ('$username')";`

The `username` field is where the user who booked the flight's username is stored, and the `$username` variable contains the current logged in user's username. What I'm trying to do is only show the fields where `$username` matches `username` (hence only showing bookings for the current user).

When I use the above code without `WHERE username IN ('$username')`, it displays all the data, but when I add the above code, it displays nothing when there are matches.

If anyone could help fix my code I would greatly appreciate it.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you include some sample data from your database? Also, if you perform this from the MySQL client, are you able to get your desired behavior?

Comment: how about `where username like '$username'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `IN` incorrectly. `IN` compares comma-separated lists of strings or values. This can be literal:

```
WHERE username IN ('user1', 'user2', 'user3')
```

OR it can come from a subquery:

```
WHERE username IN (SELECT username FROM users)
```

If you want an exact match, your `WHERE` clause should be

```
WHERE username = '$username'
```

If that still doesn't work, you MUST verify that you're sending your database the correct query.

```
echo $query_string;
```

Comment: `WHERE x IN ('a')` is the same as `WHERE x='a'`. There's no operational difference. Unless the OP has a wildcard embedded in $username, either would work the same.

Comment: @MarcB That's why I advised OP to echo the `$query_string`. +1 regardless, because this is a useful comment.

Comment: Thanks very much! I used `echo $query_string;` and it turns out I didn't declare $username properly. Such a basic thing I overlooked. Thanks again!

Comment: @Matt, it'd be kind to future readers of this answer if you clean out the parts that state `IN` is used incorrectly! OP's use of `IN`, while unusual, isn't incorrect.

Comment: @JeremySmyth just because it works doesn't make it correct. A direct comparison to one value should use `x = 'a'` format. If OP was unsure how many values were to be compared, I would agree with you. But in this case usage is incorrect.

Comment: @Matt: you are free to believe that an equality predicate "should" be used instead of an IN predicate. But it is entirely valid to use an IN predicate with a single value. There is nothing "incorrect" about this usage of `IN`. It's also valid to use `x LIKE 'a'`. There is nothing "incorrect" about such usage either.

Comment: @spencer7593 I never said it wasn't valid. I said it was incorrect usage.

Comment: @spencer7593 [mysql operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html) RTFM. `IN` is used to *"Check whether a value is within a set of values"* Since OP is looking to compare to ***one and only one*** value, `IN`, ***in this case*** is incorrect usage.